# What is This Math Font Called?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to know what is this font called? How can I reproduce it?
I know that it is neither `\mathsf{}` nor `\mathcal{}`.

Is there any reference where can I find all mathematical fonts?

[image]

Comment: Looks like `TeX Gyre Termes`, the default for `newtxmath`.

Comment: Review this document https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf titled `A Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX`.  It provides not only examples but directions for installation and usage.   p.s. Quickly found with Google search on `latex  math font catalogue pdf` terms.

Comment: See also http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/math.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something too close?

[image]

The main difficulty is with the "not `\mathcal{D}`" character. But, we can go too close using the `Zapf Chancery` characters. For these, we declare the math font:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
```

The rest of the equation can be typeset with `mathptmx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf{x}} \quad  & \sum_{i\in \mathpzc{D}}w_i \sum_{k = 1}^{K} R_{ik}^{(D)}(\mathbf{x}) \\
  \text{s. t.}\quad & \sum_{i\in \mathpzc{D}}x_{ik}P_{D_i}g_{ii}(k)\le Q_k, \quad\forall k, \\
                    & x_{ik}\in [0,1],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to combine the Zapf Chancery-style "D" with the `mathptmx` package. :-)

Comment: Strangely the subscripts in the original example are not aligned, c.f. `$x_{ik}$` and `$g_{ii}^{(k)}`, which force me to say maybe the math in @det's question wasn't created with LaTeX...

Answer (score 4):

`TeX Gyre Termes. There is a difference for the`∀` symbol :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath, newtxtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \max_{\mathbf{x}} & \sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}}w_i \sum_{k = 1}^{K} R_{ik}^{(D)}(\mathbf{x}) \\
  \text{s. t.}\quad & \sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}}x_{ik}P_{D_i}g_{ii}(k)\le Q_k, \quad\forall k, \\
                    & x_{ik}\in [0,1]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick remarks: parenthesis are not the same, spacing in the subscripts is not the same (bigger in your case), sum character is not the same.