# Math font name and differences?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to know what is the name of this math font? The math font is giving in three different pictures below. I zoomed-in in the original pdf and I took the pictures.

[image: Figure 1]

---

[image: Figure 2]

---

[image: Figure 3]

---

I read this [survey](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) about math font provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257358/what-is-this-math-font-called). The previous texSE link seems to be similar to this font but there is some differences for example in the sum symbol $\sum$.

It seems to me that the font is `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or `\usepackage{mathtime}` or `\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}`. I tried them but I found some dissimilarities in the formulas like for the $\alpha$ and the $g_{m,n}$.

It would be grateful if some one help me to figure what is this math font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\[g_{m,n} = \Gamma_m h_{m,n} d_{m,n}^{-\alpha_m},\]
\[R_{m,n} = b_{m,n} \log_2(1+\mathit{SNR}_{m,n}), \forall m,n\]
\[R_n = \sum_{m=1}^M R_{m,n} \log_2 \left( 1+\frac{p_{m,n}g_{m,n}}{b_{m,n}N_0}\right),\forall n\]
\[C1: \sum_{n=1}^N b_{m,n} \leq W_m, \forall m,\]
\[C3: \sum_{m=1}^M R_{m,n} \geq R_n^{\min}, \forall n,\]

\end{document}
```

Then, you might try `mtpro2` package. It is a commercial package, but fortunately, there is a `lite` version which you can download from [their site here](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html). The `lite` version lacks some features like bold Greek symbols, ultra-thick operators, `mathbb`, etc. But if you are interested, you might afford buying the full package.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying some free font `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}

\[g_{m,n} = \Gamma_m h_{m,n} d_{m,n}^{-\alpha_m},\]
\[R_{m,n} = b_{m,n} \log_2(1+\mathit{SNR}_{m,n}), \forall m,n\]
\[R_n = \sum_{m=1}^M R_{m,n} \log_2 \left( 1+\frac{p_{m,n}g_{m,n}}{b_{m,n}N_0}\right),\forall n\]
\[C1: \sum_{n=1}^N b_{m,n} \leq W_m, \forall m,\]
\[C3: \sum_{m=1}^M R_{m,n} \geq R_n^{\min}, \forall n,\]

\end{document}
```

[image]